# RoR: Optimal Search Package for 16k+ Record Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a database in (psql) that contains about 16,000 records; they are the titles of movies. I am trying to figure out what is the most optimal way to go about searching them (currently they are being searched via the web on a Heroku hosted website for Ruby on Rails). However, some queries such as searching for something like the word 'a' can take up to 20 seconds. I was thinking of using Sphinx however, such packages are advertised for full text searching, so I am wondering if that is appropriate for my problem. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: 20s for a query seems pretty large for only 16k records. How is your query put together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16000 records are too few both in both number and size (as you said title) to qualify for a Search Engine search. Try out normal full text search of your database. Set up the indexes for making it faster.

However this does not stop you from trying out some Search Engine like Sphinx or Solr. Both are open source. Sphinx pretty easy to setup too. But again to reiterate there is no need for this as the data size is too less and comes under the domain of Database Full Text Search.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is on PSQL then sphinx is not possible as up till now heroku postgres is not supported to work with sphinx so the remaining choice so far is to use solr which is also good for full text search and some simple steps to make it implement.

Comment: Not true - there's Flying Sphinx on Heroku (I built it), so you can use Sphinx or Solr (or Searchify/IndexTank) if you're after a solid full-text search tool for Heroku apps.